# How to fetch unique values from an array of hashes in perl

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have an array of hashes and I need to get unique values for the `college_name` from this data structure.

I have achieved the same but looks like a long process.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my %col_hash    = ();

my $college_ids = [
  {
    'term'         => 'SPRING',
    'city_code'    => '530233',
    'college_id'   => '200',
    'college_name' => 'Arts',
    'course_name'  => 'Drawing',
  },
  {
    'term'         => 'SUMMER',
    'city_code'    => '534233',
    'college_id'   => '300',
    'college_name' => 'COMMERCE',
    'course_name'  => 'FINANCE',
  }
];

foreach my $elem (@$college_ids) {
  if (exists $col_hash{'college_name'}) {
    push(@{ $col_hash{'college_name'} }, $elem->{'college_name'});
  }
  else {
    $col_hash{'college_name'} = [$elem->{'college_name'}];
  }
}

my @unique_college_names = uniq @{ $col_hash{'college_name'} };
warn Dumper(" LONG METHOD  = ", @unique_college_names);
```

I have to do the same for Term, College_name, City code.

Is there an alternate method to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most languages, Perl will allow you to `push` to a variable that is currently undefined. It will *autovivify* an array and set the variable to refer to it.

Here's a short program that demonstrates the feature

```
my $list;
push @$list, qw/ a b c /;
print $list->[1];
```

**output**

```
b
```

So there is no need to pre-define `$list` with something like `my $list = []`.

That means you can reduce your `for` loop to just

```
for my $elem (@$college_ids) {
    $col_hash{college_name} = [ $elem->{college_name} ];
}
```

However I think it is simplest to use a hash of hashes to keep track of the unique values for each category. This program uses autovivication again to increment what may be a non-existent hash element. After the loop the values of the hash are equal to the number of incidences of that value for the category, but in this case you are not interested in the counts -- it is necessary only to list the (unique) keys of the hash for each category.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %col_hash;

my $college_ids = [
  {
    'term'         => 'SPRING',
    'city_code'    => '530233',
    'college_id'   => '200',
    'college_name' => 'Arts',
    'course_name'  => 'Drawing',
  },
  {
    'term'         => 'SUMMER',
    'city_code'    => '534233',
    'college_id'   => '300',
    'college_name' => 'COMMERCE',
    'course_name'  => 'FINANCE',
  }
];

my %unique;

for my $elem (@$college_ids) {
  while (my ($key, $val) = each %$elem) {
    ++$unique{$key}{$val};
  }
}

for my $field ( qw/ term college_name city_code / ) {
  print "$field\n";
  print "  $_\n" for sort keys %{ $unique{$field} };
  print "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
term
  SPRING
  SUMMER

college_name
  Arts
  COMMERCE

city_code
  530233
  534233
```

Answer (score 1):

Borodin's answer is nearly there, but it's best to [avoid using each](http://blogs.perl.org/users/rurban/2014/04/do-not-use-each.html)

In this case removing each can make it shorter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $college_ids = [
  {
    'term'         => 'SPRING',
    'city_code'    => '530233',
    'college_id'   => '200',
    'college_name' => 'Arts',
    'course_name'  => 'Drawing',
  },
  {
    'term'         => 'SUMMER',
    'city_code'    => '534233',
    'college_id'   => '300',
    'college_name' => 'COMMERCE',
    'course_name'  => 'FINANCE',
  }
];

my %unique;
for my $elem (@$college_ids) {
  ++$unique{$_}{$elem->{$_}} for keys %$elem;
}

for my $field (qw(term college_name city_code)) {
  print "$field\n";
  print "  $_\n" for sort keys %{ $unique{$field} };
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs. I found one solution which I have pasted above.

Comment: It is foolish to proscribe a construct just because it has problems in specific situations. `each` is very useful for iterating over an entire hash without the additional time and noise that it takes to extract the hash value corresponding to each key. The link that you offer calls out issues with modifying a hash within a loop that uses `each`. Note that a simple `for` loop has the same problem, and in most other languages as well as Perl. More important is that `each` isn't reentrant. So yes, care must be taken to avoid nesting loops that use `each`, and it should never be used in callable c

Answer (score -1):

I did it with this one line. No loops.

```
my %uniq_colleges = map { $_->{'college_name'} => 1 } @$college_ids;
```

Later `keys %uniq_colleges` will give me the list of unique colleges.

Thanks

Comment: `map` is no less a looping structure than `for`.  Also, you don't seem to be answering your own question, which asks about how to extract all unique values for a number of different keys.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for the question, Since I am storing the College_names into the Hash, Hash keys being unique; solves the problem.